# Angular2 Dynamic Components

Tags: angular, components, viewchild

I'm pretty new to **Angular2** and I haven't found a solution to what I'm trying to do. I'll try to explain with the following example.

Let's say we have a parent component *A* which could include either a child component *X* or *Y*.
That could be easily solved using a viewchild.

But, **what if we wanted to load the child components dynamically** without code duplication?

*Real example :*

- Component U : Component called by the user which calls the component
  A and injects a child component (X or Y) according to the user's
  choice.
- Component A : Grid container which could be a table, a panel or
  whatever.
- Component X : View containing rows for the service S1
- Component Y : View containing rows for the service S2

**The aim would be to easily change the container, changing all the views automatically .**

There must be a way to do that, I just can't find a good and clean solution for that sort of need.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: See the Angular2 Component Router. It is exactly what you are aking for.

Comment: I'll have al look at it, thanks!

Comment: @K3v1n sorry, are you talking about the basic [Angular2 router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) ? 
If so, I am not sure it's exactly what I am looking for. 
Unless there are features I am not aware of, the angular router is supposed to redirect the user's request to a component, what I'm trying to do is a little bit more complex than that.

Comment: Another example: 

Let's say we have a component A and in its template there's something like : 
  
<componentX *ngIf="choice == 1" >  
<componentY *ngIf="choice == 2" >  
  
And we want to inject the child component rather than doing if, if, if

Comment: you should know that you can load a component programmatically: (like `this.router.navigate(["/path/of/component/route"])`). So you can make it load a component depending on the user's choice.

Comment: Again, I'm not trying to just navigate to a component programmatically, I'm trying to load a component and include it in a parent component dynamically which means injecting a child component into a parent component.
Anyway, I found out that in previous releases it was possible to do that using DynamicComponentLoader and ComponentResolver which have been deprecated in the final release.

Comment: you might not have noticed that the Angular2 Router needs a `<router-outlet>` to know where you want to put the resulting loaded component. It's best i keep it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Angular2 Component Router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) as so:

(Note: For simplicity reasons, I have not added input elements and instead, used `a` elements. The same procedure applies though, call a function to tell the router to insert the loaded component into the `<router-outlet>`)

app.component.ts

```
import { Component }       from '@angular/core';
import { Router }       from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div>
            <!-- to show how the function can be called -->
            <a href="#" (click)="load('/page1')">Page 1</a>

            <!-- Right way with links -->
            <a href="#" routerLink="/page1">Page 1</a>

            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router)

    load(path: string): void {
        this.router.navigate([path]);
    }
}
```

app.routing.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }   from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule }  from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "page1",
        component: "PageOneComponent"
    }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const appRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { appRouting, appRoutingProviders }  from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        appRouting,
    ],
    declarations: [
        RootComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        appRoutingProviders
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Cheers!

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now.

Comment: Anyway, I have got a router set up in my app already and I would need to put a second one in my component, which would be possible naming the router-outlets (<router-outlet name="xxx">). That might work.
However, using the router to dynamically show a child component in a parent component looks to me more a workaround rather than a proper solution. Don't you agree?

Comment: Also, would you add a router component for each component that needs to be generic?

Imagine a grid-container component like the following : 

template : 
`<div class="container">
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">{{this.title}}</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <injected-component />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`

Anyway, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Comment code formatting is quite horrible :P. And you're always welcome! :)

Comment: I do agree that it kinda seems like a workaround. but AFAIK i haven't seen any well-established framework for your sort of thing. The router's the closest thing to it